# Which Haskell GLSL binding supports multiple framebuffers?

Tags: opengl, haskell, lua, glsl, love2d

I'm trying to implement two pass Gaussian blur using GLSL with **Haskell** and I don't know which library should I use to achieve result similar to the Löve2D Lua code presented below:

#### Löve2d code (`main.lua`)

```lua
LG = love.graphics

function love.load()
    time = love.timer.getTime()
    img = LG.newImage("moonbow.jpg")
    blur_pass = LG.newShader("pass.gs")
    horizontal_canvas = LG.newCanvas(img:getDimensions())
    vertical_canvas = LG.newCanvas(img:getDimensions())
    LG.setCanvas(horizontal_canvas)
    LG.setShader(blur_pass)
    blur_pass:send("horizontal", true)
    blur_pass:send("blurSize", 1 / img:getWidth())
    LG.draw(img)
    LG.setCanvas(vertical_canvas)
    blur_pass:send("horizontal", false)
    blur_pass:send("blurSize", 1 / img:getHeight())
    LG.draw(horizontal_canvas)
    LG.setShader()
    LG.setCanvas()
    time = love.timer.getTime() - time
end

function love.draw()
    LG.draw(vertical_canvas)
    LG.print("Time: " .. time * 10 .. "ms", 12, 12)
end
```

#### Löve2d GLSL shader (`pass.gs` file)

```c++
float gauss[51] = float[](0.9637, 0.9606, 0.9572, 0.9533, 0.9489, 0.9438, 0.9379, 0.9311, 0.9231, 0.9136, 0.9023, 0.8886, 0.8720, 0.8515, 0.8259, 0.7934, 0.7515, 0.6966, 0.6236, 0.5258, 0.3963, 0.2354, 0.0764, 0.0031, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0031, 0.0764, 0.2354, 0.3963, 0.5258, 0.6236, 0.6966, 0.7515, 0.7934, 0.8259, 0.8515, 0.8720, 0.8886, 0.9023, 0.9136, 0.9231, 0.9311, 0.9379, 0.9438, 0.9489, 0.9533, 0.9572, 0.9606, 0.9637);

extern float blurSize;
extern bool horizontal;

vec4 effect(vec4 _color, Image texture, vec2 texture_coords, vec2 screen_coords) {
    vec4 result = vec4(0);
    float sum = 0.0;
    if(horizontal) {
        for(int i = 0; i <= 51; i++) {
            result += Texel(texture, vec2(texture_coords.x - (float(i) - 25)*blurSize, texture_coords.y)) * (1.0 - gauss[i]);
            sum += (1.0 - gauss[i]);
        }
    } else {
        for(int i = 0; i <= 51; i++) {
            result += Texel(texture, vec2(texture_coords.x, texture_coords.y - (float(i) - 25)*blurSize)) * (1.0 - gauss[i]);
            sum += (1.0 - gauss[i]);
        }        
    }
    return result / sum;
}
```

I especially care about the **ease of use** of the library, **multiple framebuffers (Canvases)** and simple way of **sending** stuff to GLSL and back.
So, Which Haskell GLSL binding do you recommend?

Comment: I'm not an OpenGL expert, but I think `vinyl-gl` handles the second half of your question (marshalling things to GLSL and back).